# Validate incoming data with unique check from database in hapijs with JOI

Tags: hapi.js, joi

Is there any way in which I can validate API parameter with JOI plugin which can check uniqueness with database field. For example we can validate any parameter or incoming data in Laravel with specific validation rules as given below.

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address' 

Name of table: users 
Name of column: email_address
required validation: unique
```

with the help of this validation rule in Laravel we can validate email address to be unique with respect to specific column in database. Similar kind of validation I need to put in hapijs.